# How to save user's choice of theme of web pages

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, themes

I have a simple web app, it's done with several JSP pages. I would like to add some style to it. I would like to provide some color theme options say like in a drop down box. I have little basic knowledge of CSS. Here are my questions:

1. I think I should have all styles in one CSS file, and use format like `selector#different_ids {property:value}` to keep all styles, is that correct?
2. Once a theme is selected, how should it be saved? using `request.getParameter("")` every time or use JavaScript?
3. How can I change the theme according to the saved selection? Would it be correct if I use `if..else if` in Java, and associate each tag with corresponding id for `different_ids`?
4. How can the theme selection be passed from page to page? Should it be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- create a cookie for the selection.
  that will pass the selection from
  page to page.
- put each theme into    different css
  files.
- link the appropriate css file
  according to the    selection